# Is there a difference between Rect3D.SizeX and Rect3D.Size.X?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

It seems like a strange convenience property, only saving one character. Is there some important difference between using `SizeX` and `Size.X`? And why is there a `SizeX` property, but not a `LocationX` property?

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.rect3d.sizex%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) does not mention any particular difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some important difference between using SizeX and Size.X?

When it doubt, take a look at it with [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) or equivalent tool. The `Size` property does this:

```
if (IsEmpty)
{
    return Size3D.Empty;
}
return new Size3D(this._sizeX, this._sizeY, this._sizeZ);
```

And `SizeX` does:

```
return this._sizeX;
```

They are both based off of the private field `_sizeX`, so no, the value of them will always be the same. It's just a way of getting different data structures to better suit your needs.

> And why is there a `SizeX` property, but not a `LocationX` property?

There are properties for location, they are `Location.X` and just `X`, both of which use the private field `_x`. it just doesn't follow the same naming convetion as `Size`.

Answer (score 0):

SizeX is a double with the value, while Rect3D.Size is a Size3D object which has the values like X and Y.

Look at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.rect3d.size(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score -1):

**No**, there is no difference.

With **SizeX** you have a direct access to the X Property of the [Size3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.size3d.aspx) Structure

With **Size** you have access to the [Size3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.size3d.aspx) Sturcture (X,Y,Z,Empty,...)

Comment: -1: the SizeX property does not function as an accessor to a Size3D structure, it's the other way around.